# Завершение работы программы, находясь в контексте отладчика

Tags: python, отладка

При использовании отладчика [ipdb](https://pypi.org/project/ipdb), а конкретно его контекстного режима `launch_ipdb_on_exception`, возник вопрос, как осуществить выход из программы, не используя остановку процесса по <kbd>Сtrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.

Если при использовании обычных точек останова выход из отладчика и завершение программы осуществляется по <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> комбинации:

```
while True:
    ipdb.set_trace()  # press Ctrl+D > Exiting Debugger.
```

то при использовании такой формы вызова программа не завершается, а переходит к следующей итерации цикла:

```
while True:
    with ipdb.launch_ipdb_on_exception():
        raise Exception  # press Ctrl+D > next iteration
```

Завершить выполнение из отладчика по вызову `sys.exit()` нельзя.

Comment: вы не хотите продолжать цикл и не хотите останавливать процесс по Ctrl+Z. Вы хотите завершить процесс? (kill %1 после Ctrl+Z). При запуске как `python -m ipdb <script>` происходит выход по Ctrl+D.

Comment: @jfs это понятно, что можно убить процесс после остановки. Еще обнаружил, что выход возможен по `os._exit`, может ли это значить, что отладчиком создается отдельный поток?

Comment: вы можете легко проверить: `threading.current_thread()`